# Is it possible to cache a runtime compiled class?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, hazelcast

Whenever I try to cache the result of a method that compile in runtime a Java class, the first time everything works, but the second one (when it's supose that will get the result from cache) it give me a `ClassNotFoundException`. I don't know if this is just impossible to implement or if I am doing something wrong.

This is how I call the method with cache:

```
public void execute() throws Exception {
    MyClass myclass = new MyClass();
    String code = "This is a really long JavaClass that implements CompiledClass"; // Retrieve JavaCode from somewhere
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            CompiledClass obj = myclass.getInstance("NameClassToCompile", code);
    }
}
```

This is the class with the method cachable:

```
@Component
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "myCache")
public class MyClass implements SomeClass {

    @Override
    @Cacheable(key = "#name")
    public CompiledClass getInstance(String name, String code) throws CustomException {
        try {
            // Save source in .java file.
            File root = Files.createTempDirectory(null).toFile();
            File sourceFile = new File(root, (this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + File.separator + name).replace('.', '/') + ".java");
            sourceFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
            Files.write(sourceFile.toPath(), code.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

            // Compile source file.
            JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
            compiler.run(null, null, null, sourceFile.getPath());

            // Load and instantiate compiled class.
            Class<?> cls;
            try (URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[]{root.toURI().toURL()})) {
                cls = Class.forName((this.getClass().getPackage().getName() + "." + name), true, classLoader);
            }
            return (CompiledClass) cls.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException | NoSuchMethodException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            throw new CustomException("didn't work", e);
        }
    }
```

And I get this Exception:

```
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mycompany.myartifact.mypackage.NameClassToCompile
```

And this is how I have my Hazelcast configuration:

```
@Bean
public Config hazelCastConfig() {
    return new Config()
        .setInstanceName("hazelcast")
        .addMapConfig(
            new MapConfig()
                .setName("myCache")
                .setMaxSizeConfig(new MaxSizeConfig(200, MaxSizeConfig.MaxSizePolicy.FREE_HEAP_SIZE))
                .setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU)
                .setTimeToLiveSeconds(20));
}
```

This is the Interface that implement all compiled classes.

```
public interface CompiledClass extends Serializable {

    Long calculateSomething(String some);
}
```

This is an example of code to compile on runtime:

```
public class NameClassToCompile implements CompiledClass {
     @Override
     Long calculateSomething(String some) {
         return Long.valueOf(name.length());
     }
}
```

Comment: what is the content of NameClassToCompile, and is interface SomeClass extends Serializable?

Comment: I made a mistake on my example. I have updated the question. And yes, it does extends Serializable.

Comment: Can you also show the class definition of NameClassToCompile?